# Linear Regression could not convert string to float

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am trying to find a relationship between UCAS points and Final university mark (Final) through linear regression, I am using [This](https://pythonspot.com/linear-regression/) tutorial

I get the following error at

```
plt.scatter(X_test, Y_test,  color='black')
```

> could not convert string to float:

I have checked the type and "Total UCAS Points" column is of class str and "Final" is of type numpy.float64'

I have tried to convert the str to a float through doing the following:

```
pd.to_numeric("Total UCAS Points")
```

But keep getting the error message:

> Unable to parse string "Total UCAS Points" at position 0

I have also tried to ignore the error but this does not seem to change the type to float and remains a str

here is a sample of my csv file:

Total UCAS Points:
280
280
240
240
360
360
360
360
630

Final:
58
46
62
64
48
56
54
30

```
df = df.replace(np.nan, -1)

X = df['Total UCAS Points']
Y = df['Final']

pd.to_numeric("Total UCAS Points")

print(type(Y[2]))


X=X.reshape(len(X),1)
Y=Y.reshape(len(Y),1)

# Split the data into training/testing sets
X_train = X[:-2500]
X_test = X[-2500:]

# Split the targets into training/testing sets
Y_train = Y[:-2500]
Y_test = Y[-2500:]

# Plot outputs
plt.scatter(X_test, Y_test,  color='black')
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a list of data to [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html), not a column name from your data frame.  Try this:

```
X = pd.to_numeric(X)  # in place of pd.to_numeric("Total UCAS Points")
```

Comment: Thank you, I now realise how stupid this question was. Would you be guide me how I can remove empty string from my "Total UCAS Points" I thought the df.replace would handle that but I guess thats only for NaN values. I am now getting the following error: Unable to parse string "               " at position 22.

Comment: I was able to find that: df = df.replace(r'^\s+$', np.nan, regex=True) works for empty spaces.